# How to get rpm file path in spec file

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to copy the installed rpm file to some directory during %post. Like

```
%post
cp rpm_path %_prefix/rpm/
```

Is there any way to get rpm file path in spec file?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

However, you can achieve it on the DNF level, by using `local` plugin. Or writing a similar plugin.

https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf-plugins-core/blob/master/plugins/local.py